# TrustedInstaller group on my Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7

how can I list the members of the TrustedInstaller group on my Windows 7 PC?

Answer (score 2):

TrustedInstaller is actually a service not a specific user account or group of accounts. The service has a display name of *Windows Modules Installer*. The service is assigned a SID (`S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271478464`) and that SID by default has ownership of critical windows files.